# What does "featured event" mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

I read this phrase "featured event" in the websites of some universities. I know the word "feature", but I cannot figure out the meaning of the juxtaposition. Could you please give me some synonyms for "featured event"?

Comment: In case you might forget, *feature* can be used as either a noun and a verb.

Comment: So "featured event" means simply "event made emphasized"?

Comment: You can understand it that way. A more straightforward way is "an/the event that is featured".

Comment: Ah much appreciated~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Featured" is the modifying the Event. Namly it is the Main event and is telling the reader this will be the primary event to see or attend.